# Interpretation of a line integral in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
Suppose $f\colon \Omega\subset \C\to\C$ is a holomorphic function and $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Omega$ is a continuous path.

If $\Omega=\C\setminus\{0\}$, $\gamma(t):= e^{2\pi i t}$ and $f(z)=1/z$ then for $t\in[0,1]$ the formula $$f(\gamma(t))=f(\gamma(0))\cdot e^{\int_{\gamma|_{[0,t]}}f(z)dz}$$
holds true.

Is this true in general? Can a similar statement be made about vector fields on a manifold, for example using a spin structure?

Comment: If my mental calculations are correct, the fact $f=\log'$ is essential.

Comment: Reasonable, thank you.